# Facebook SDK error win32 cmd with unity

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine

i tried to implement facebook SDK 7.9.4 so i can use it for leaderboards, ect... but i have some issues with it.

After the asset installed in my project and i go to facebook settings, i had got this error:

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='cmd', CommandLine='/Cecho "xxx" | openssl 
base64', CurrentDirectory=''
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell 
(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process 
process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo 
startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookAndroidUtil.DoesCommandExist (System.String 
command)
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookAndroidUtil.get_DebugKeyHash ()
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookAndroidUtil.get_SetupProperly ()
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookSettingsEditor.AndroidUtilGUI ()
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookSettingsEditor.OnInspectorGUI ()
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditor (UnityEditor.Editor editor, Int32 
editorIndex, Boolean rebuildOptimizedGUIBlock, System.Boolean& 
showImportedObjectBarNext, UnityEngine.Rect& importedObjectBarRect) (at 
C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1235)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
```

I searched online, and nothing worked.

I installed openssl win64 and include it in variable environnements. I also put jdk path in it. But it still not working.

My project and Android SDk folder are in a different drive (E:) than openssl and jdk drive (C:). (i did that because i lack of space on C:HD).

I put my whole project on C: but the error continues to show.

How can i fix that?

Thanks a lot!

Regards, Sam.

Comment: Just a suggestion, configure your pc such that you are able to play an empty Unity project onto an android device. Once you know the configuration is ok, move on to integrating facebook

Comment: Well i create a new empty project, and i switch to android platform. It builds succesfully, and when i'm importing facebook sdk, the error shows off again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i remember, this code is part of the Facebook SDK for Unity (it runs openssl to get the right keyhash for your game).

If i recall correctly, you must have openssl in your path (add it to the PATH environment variable), since the Facebook code is attempting to call the command 'openssl', assuming it can be run from anywhere.

This will fail, unless openssl is in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed my error by adding in

Enviroment variable > System variable > PATH > Edit > New

"C:\Windows\System32"

in my pc, system 32 path was not mentionned.